# Is there a way to make Eclipse+PyDev display function documentation like Python's help() would?

Tags: python, eclipse, popup, pydev, docstring

I would like to force Eclipse to show Python's help output in the popup instead of the whole function, i.e. given:

```
def myFunc(arg):
    '''Function description'''
    return 1
```

I would like the code assist popup to contain only "Function description" and not "return 1"

Comment: Have you read the Pydev and Eclipse documentation or source and figured out specifically what you would need to change?

Answer (score 4):

Try ticking 'Show docstrings?' in 'Window -> Preferences -> Pydev -> Editor -> Hover'.